# How to upload an image from assets folder to server in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, file, upload, assets

**I need to let user pick an image from assets/images directory, I did it.
now i need to upload image selected to backend guy, i used this snap of code to convert asset path to file :**

```
  Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load('$path');
    final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
    return file;
  }
```

**I test the file in this line**

```
final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
```

**and got this as file path:**

```
'/data/user/0/com.mohra.app/cache/assets/images/svg/dream_icons/dream-icon-9.png'
```

**but error i got in this line :**

```
await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
```

**the error is :**

```
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.mohra.app/cache/assets/images/svg/dream_icons/dream-icon-9.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

**any one can help how to create file from assets path ??**

Comment: Why would you want to store it in an intermediate file? It seems like an unnecessary step. Read from assets, write to file, read from file, upload to server?? Cut out the middle two steps: read from assets, upload to server from memory.

Comment: Good idea, I will give it a try and let you know the result.

Comment: @RichardHeap
i got this when i try to pass path of file like 'assets/images/example.png': 
error: 
Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = 'assets/images/svg/dream_icons/dream-icon-10.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: No, load it into memory like you are now: `await rootBundle.load('$path')` then use the `MultipartFile.fromBytes` constructor.